# Failed to open TCP connection when upgrading Rubygems

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, updates, macos-ventura

I'm on MacOS Ventura 13.0 and I'm trying to [upgrade Rubygems](https://rubygems.org/pages/download).

```
$ gem update --system
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Failed to open TCP connection to localhost:8808 (Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 8808) (http://localhost:8808/specs.4.8.gz)
```

How can I solve the error?

Comment: Looks like it's configured with some kind of local proxy?

Comment: Maybe I made something unwanted e.g. configuration if Rubygems has one. I also tried to install Rubygems from packages: Rubygems was upgraded but the above-mentioned error persists. Any help to make it to work would be appreciated.

Comment: Check if any sort of proxy setting is enabled, even in System Preferences or any suspicious `env` you may have. It's just using some external settings.

Comment: Also check `~/.bundle/config` -- you may have configured a caching proxy like [gemstash](https://github.com/rubygems/gemstash) that is no longer running, or otherwise misconfigured this setting.

Comment: @anothermh, in `~/.bundle/config` I've just `--- BUNDLE_PATH: "vendor/cache"`. Where can I exactly see otherwhere? For example, in System Preferences, as said by @tadman, I don't know where to look for... and where may I've `env` statements?

Comment: OK, i solved by running in terminal the command `gem sources -r SOURCE_URI`. I'll post this as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: in the Terminal, `cd` your project folder and run the command `gem sources -r SOURCE_URI` where `SOURCE_URI` is the source to remove.